# Can you use PHP to connect with Azure CosmosDB?

Tags: php, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'm currently building a webapp and I need to use CosmosDB. I've been trying to find a connection script for PHP but I can't seem to find a straight answer.

So my question is, can I use PHP to connect with Azure Cosmos DB? I have a script from Unity that parses data to CosmosDB as JSON files, but can I connect to Azure using PHP? And what method would be best used to access the data?

If so, is there an API or a certain connect script that I need? I'm open for suggestions, but a straight answer would be of great help because I'm currently using a shared hosting from Bluehost so I'm stuck with the typical LAMP configuration.

Btw if you somehow find this post familiar, it's because I posted this also in Reddit half an hour ago.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use Azure Cosmos DB as a MongoDB, you can use its MongoDB Api and the "official" MongoDB library.

### Getting the connection string

To know the connection string you can follow the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/azure/cosmos-db/connect-mongodb-account#GetCustomConnection.

From there:

1. In an Internet browser, sign in to the Azure portal.
2. In the Azure Cosmos DB blade, select the API for MongoDB account.
3. In the left pane of the account blade, click Connection String.
4. The Connection String blade opens. It has all the information necessary to connect to the account by using a driver for MongoDB, including a preconstructed connection string.

Azure Cosmos DB supports the standard MongoDB connection string URI format, with a couple of specific requirements: Azure Cosmos DB accounts require authentication and secure communication via SSL. So, the connection string format is:

```
mongodb://username:password@host:port/[database]?ssl=true
```

The values of this string are available in the Connection String blade shown earlier:

- Username (required): Azure Cosmos DB account name.
- Password (required): Azure Cosmos DB account password.
- Host (required): FQDN of the Azure Cosmos DB account.
- Port (required): 10255.
- Database (optional): The database that the connection uses. If no database is provided, the default database is "test."
- ssl=true (required)

For example, consider the account shown in the Connection String blade. A valid connection string is:

```
mongodb://contoso123:0Fc3IolnL12312asdfawejunASDF@asdfYXX2t8a97kghVcUzcDv98hawelufhawefafnoQRGwNj2nMPL1Y9qsIr9Srdw==@contoso123.documents.azure.com:10255/mydatabase?ssl=true
```

### Access data

And for the current use in PHP you can use http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.tutorial.library.php

Install the library by running:

```
$ composer require mongodb/mongodb
```

Aan example, this is how you insert a document into the beers collection of the demo database:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php'; // include Composer's autoloader

$client = new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://localhost:27017");
$collection = $client->demo->beers;

$result = $collection->insertOne( [ 'name' => 'Hinterland', 'brewery' => 'BrewDog' ] );

echo "Inserted with Object ID '{$result->getInsertedId()}'";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

clone https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-cosmos-db-graph-php-getting-started.git
then in connect.php fill in your credentials

```
$db = new Connection([
    'host' => '<your_server_address>.graphs.azure.com',
    'username' => '/dbs/<db>/colls/<coll>',
    'password' => 'your_primary_key'
    ,'port' => '443'
    // Required parameter
    ,'ssl' => TRUE
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Azure CosmosDB (DocumentDB API) currently doesn't have an official PHP SDK.

You can interact with CosmosDB using either the [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/documentdb/) or a community driver like [AzureDocumentDB-PHP](https://github.com/cocteau666/AzureDocumentDB-PHP).

Comment: does **AzureDocumentDB-PHP** Wrapper work for Laravel ? @Aaron Chen